# CSS: Text on Hover while keeping self correcting grid layout

Tags: css, html

http://codepen.io/tylerkung/pen/Bukzy

I've implemented the self-correcting grid, so that when you resize the browser window, the 3 images will simply stack on top of each other.

I've also been able to make the images fade on mouseover.

But the last bit I wanted to add was to display a text on mouseover which seems tricky to me.

I'm just learning CSS so any help/articles/advice would be appreciated!

Comment: This really belongs on StackOverflow.com, but.... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dsxek (rough but workable)

Comment: The main issue you have is you can't control the image opacity and the text hover at the same time with CSS.

Comment: I would use Java Script with jQuery, it is way way easier :).

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the opacity of the text when the container link is hovered so use this:

```
.wrapper:hover .text{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

instead of

```
.text:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

See **[updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fxqkB)**

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple tooltip, you may just add `title` attribute on each of the image.